# Reset Countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown, restart

I found a countdown that is suitable for my web-project. I want that the countdown restarts every Friday at 9 am. Could someone give me a hint? Here is the code:

```
(function(){
   const days = document.getElementById("days");
   const hours = document.getElementById("hours");
   const minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
   const seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
   const currentDate = new Date().getFullYear();

  const concertDate = new Date(`June 19 ${currentDate} 09:00:00`);

  function updateCountdown() {
     const currentTime = new Date();
     const diff = concertDate - currentTime;

     const d = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
     const h = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;
     const m = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60;
     const s = Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60;

     days.innerHTML = d;
     hours.innerHTML = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h;
     minutes.innerHTML = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
     seconds.innerHTML = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;
}

setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

})();
```

Comment: Hey Maria , https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. In the countdown function, add an if statement that checks whether the `diff <= 0` - if it is (countdown expired), simply add one week of time to the concertDate, and the new countdown starts.

For this to work, firstly you have to change the `concertDate` declaration to `let concertDate` to allow it to be changed later on. And also, you need to use `.getTime()` for the concert that will give you the time of that date in miliseconds (this makes adding one week of time at the end possible).

```
(function(){
 const days = document.getElementById("days");
 const hours = document.getElementById("hours");
 const minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
 const seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
 const currentDate = new Date().getFullYear();

 let concertDate = new Date(`June 19 ${currentDate} 09:00:00`).getTime();

 function updateCountdown() {
 const currentTime = new Date();
 const diff = concertDate - currentTime;

 const d = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
 const h = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;
 const m = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60;
 const s = Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60;

 days.innerHTML = d;
 hours.innerHTML = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h;
 minutes.innerHTML = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
 seconds.innerHTML = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;

 if (diff <= 0) {
    concertDate = concertDate + (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7); //add one week to concert date
    }   
  }

setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

})();
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [cron]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron;

Your cron time should be like  0 9 * * 5